# Entity Framework code-first lazy loading of navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework code-first project, where one my objects has:

```
public virtual List<Transaction> Transactions { get; private set; }
```

It will of course be lazy-loaded, which is what I want. Now, on the same object, I want to introduce a 'convenience property', which does some filtering for me:

```
public virtual List<Transaction> EnabledTransactions
{
    get
    {
        // TODO: .AsQueryable<Transaction>(); ?
        return this.Transactions.Where(t => !t.Disabled).ToList();
    }
}
```

Questions:

- Does this new property have to be `virtual` or not? If it's not `virtual`, will .NET try to load it and hence negate the lazy loading?
- Since none of them is `IQueryable` (I understand we can't have it as navigation property), does it mean that anyone doing `account.Transactions.Where(t => t.Date <= someDate)` would force a complete eager load of the whole collection, instead of just getting the items that satisfy the predicate?

Comment: EF will only override the virtual navigation property and do nothing with your convenience property.  If you "get" the convenience property, the override of the navigation property will kick in and load the related entities at that point. That said, making it `virtual` will not hurt anything - it would just allow someone to change that behavior if they subclass the entity (which would decouple it from EF).

Comment: You _might_ add a null check for `this.Transactions` just to be safe, though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment on the first question. I am not checking for null, because in my `public ctor` this property is initialized to empty list and in the `protected ctor` EF sets it to empty list too.

Comment: `EnabledTransactions` itself doesn't lazy load. EF doesn't even know anything about it (it shouldn't be mapped). So `virtual` has no bearing on lazy loading or not.